# Is the last set of High Point Binoculars that I'm missing, looking at the Downtown Fort?

Tags: sunset-overdrive

Not ''where'' is it, but does it exist?

There's 20 High Points, I've found 19, and most seem to be looking at important landmarks or locations:

1. The beach at the south of Little Tokyo
2. The Scabs' Bridge
3. The Robot Factory / Dawn Of The Rise Of The Fallen Machines Zone
4. The Wall before the Robot Factory
5. The Radio Tower / Fizzie Boss Battle
6. Concert Hall
7. Fizzco Building / Destroyed at Game's End
8. Kickass Brewing Co / Brewery Player Fort
9. The Nuclear Power Plant
10. The Hospital
11. The lighthouse pier
12. The Harbor Player Fort, a.k.a "ferry to nowhere" / Pelican Ferry.
13. The top of the train station, "World's Largest!" "Sunset City Transit"
14. Farmer Fong's
15. The amusement park
16. The edge of the playspace, somewhere near Flotsam.
17. The OverCharge launch party
18. Fizzco Campus / Outside Fizzco HQ
19. GentriFly Lofts

I've looked over the zones each of those spots are in, and if I'm right on my new hypothesis that the Points are evenly split between the four zones, then my last Point should be somewhere in Little Tokyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's pointing at the island with poles that have red lights, to the left of Downtown, below the Robot Factory.

There's no binoculars looking at the Hepcat's 50's Diner nor the Downtown Fort.